How to fix webpack breaking for a specific package?
So, lately, I've been tasked to develop a new tool, and to accomplish that I needed to install the @mui/x-charts package. After I was done coding and testing, I tried to build it for production, However, I kept getting this error:
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/transitions/utils.js 9:40
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   } = props;
|   return {
>     duration: style.transitionDuration ?? (typeof timeout === 'number' ? timeout : timeout[options.mode] || 0),
|     easing: style.transitionTimingFunction ?? (typeof easing === 'object' ? easing[options.mode] : easing),
|     delay: style.transitionDelay
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/material/Slide/Slide.js 13:0-69 122:4-10 128:28-46 150:28-46
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/material/Slide/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/material/index.js
 @ ./src/paginas/simuladores/calculadora_juros_compostos/form/index.js
 @ ./src/paginas/simuladores/calculadora_juros_compostos/index.js
 @ ./simuladores/simuladores.js

The thing is, it's not just this error specifically, it happens for almost any file inside the @mui package. This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "produtos_esb",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.16.7",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.2",
    "@mui/x-charts": "^7.19.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.18.1",
    "acorn": "^6.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-sass-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-currency-masked-input": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-google-charts": "^5.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-number-format": "^4.9.4",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.0",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.7",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-sticky-box": "^2.0.5",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.10.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
    "url-loader": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "local": "webpack --config webpack.config.local.js --mode development",
    "ts1": "webpack --config webpack.config.ts1.js --mode development",
    "prod": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --mode production",
    "prod-sem-hash": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod-sem-hash.js --mode production",
    "r7": "webpack --config webpack.config.r7.js --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.25.7",
    "@gfx/zopfli": "^1.0.14",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  }
}


Here is my webpack file:
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const zopfli = require('@gfx/zopfli');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './simuladores/simuladores.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            compressionOptions: {
                numiterations: 15,
            },
            algorithm(input, compressionOptions, callback) {
                return zopfli.gzip(input, compressionOptions, callback);
            }
        }),

    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'..','..','nginx','build'),
        filename: 'simuladores_[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: 'sim.chk.[name]_[hash].js',
        publicPath: 'https://ferramentas.educandoseubolso.com/build/',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: ['file-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: ['url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: ['file-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all'
                },
            },
        },
    },
};


Does anybody know what is going on?
thanks in advance!!
I was expecting the build to work as it usually does.

What was different in the testing?

The code worked perfectly on my machine(running with npm start). However, the build command started to throw this error after I added the new package
